# Complex Forms Generating Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am working on an application that allows students to create a catalog of courses they are taking for a semester.  I have created models for user; course; subject and category.  Users can have many courses.  Each course can have many subjects and categories.  The tables for courses, subjects and categories include the following:

```
Catalog:  user_id and course_id
Courses: user_id; coursedetail_id, subject_id and category_id 
Coursedetail:  name; description
Subject: name; description
Category: name; description
```

The idea is that an Admin can create a list of courses; subjects and categories and that the user can select the courses they want to add to their catalog.  I have seperated courses and coursedetails because I envision that the coursedetails will grow overtime and the courses table will allow me to join the user_id and cousres details to rreport on if necessary.

I attempted to follow Ryan's railscast on Complex Forms thinking that that I should use a complex form and has many relationship to get things working -- but I get **an error in the catalog controller - cannot locate catalog_id** which I know is in the table.  I am now not sure if complex forms is the way to go or I should be looking at another direction to get the appropriate form in place.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to move ina different direction and feel that the question I posed may have been to broad to get a direct response.  for that I apologize.  I will in the future make sure questions are specific and backed up by clear code to get the apporpriate feedback and response.